# Proving $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2!2^4}-\frac{3!!}{3!2^6}-\frac{5!!}{4!2^8}-\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2!2^4}-\frac{3!!}{3!2^6}-\frac{5!!}{4!2^8}-\cdots$$
I wanted to prove it by using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{2}$, but I couldnt do.

Comment: Question why you did not just write$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2!2^4}-\frac{3!!}{3!2^6}-\frac{5!!}{4!2^8}-...$$

Comment: @Elaqqad As you like.

Comment: @Elaqqad For the same reason some people choose to write $\pi = (\sum \text{Ramanujan formula})^{-1}$. $\sqrt{2}$ is a more cool result than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Soke when it's already proven it's cool to rewrite it in a beautiful formula, but when we are trying to prove something it's better to get rid of the elegance in order to see the logic !!

Comment: @Elaqqad Well, it's not *too* hard to go between each form. I'd rather see the beautiful form as what we want to prove and then make that easy step to see the logic when we try to prove it.

Comment: This is a simple [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2):

As Lucian pointed out, we can write

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-1)(\frac{1}{2}-2)\cdots(\frac{1}{2}-(k-1))}{k!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}$

$\displaystyle=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1(-1)(-3)(-5)\cdots(-(2k-1))}{k!2^k}\cdot\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{k!2^{2k}}$

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{3}{4}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)!2^{2n+2}}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!8^{n}}$$
that follows from:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}z^n = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}-2z}{2z}.\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ is just a minor variation of the [generating function for Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).